# Has anyone had experience filtering products, based on the quantity at a retail location?

Tags: filter

I am trying to set up a product filter where I can filter by: Store location, type of product, and price.

I have 36 retails locations in total, and only want to display products that have a greater quantity then 0. The only things that changes from location to location is the quantity.

I have used the module "reefine" before for something similar, but don't believe it would work in this case. As i am importing the information from a ".csv" file using the module "data grab", which needs its own channel field for each row in the .csv file.

I need to show the quantity of product X, at retail location Y.

I am thinking modules might not be the way to go for this project. Just wanted to ask and see if anyone has run into something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [**Numeric Matching**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#numeric-matching) with the [**search=""**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name) parameter may help. This is a parameter for the `channel:entries` tag.

> If you have a field containing numeric data, you may use greater-than
>   or less-than operators to search through them.
>
> search:numeric_field="<20"
>   search:numeric_field=">20"
>   search:numeric_field="<=20"
>   search:numeric_field=">=20"

---

If you need complete search functionality these are the two search addons to check out:

http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search
http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/

You'll need to read their docs to make sure they do exactly what you need.

Comment: Awesome! I'll do some reading. Thanks for the help.